# Android alert dialog does not fit to image

Tags: android, image, android-alertdialog

I have the following layout for alertdialog (I want alert dialog with only image in it)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageImageViewId"
        android:src="@drawable/stub" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The result I get is:
http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/3333/imagenp.png

You can see that the alert dialog is larger than the image itself...

What can be done so it will fit?

Comment: You could try `android:background` on the `LinearLayout` and remove the image view. It may or may not work. And it might cause issues with the size of the image, but it's probably worth trying

Answer (score 0):

i think alert dialog has default padding try custom dialog instead.