# How to fit dialog to image?

Tags: android, image, dialog

I'm creating `DialogFragment` using `ActionBarSherlock`. I'm passing an id of the image to `DialogFragment`. It contains only of ImageView:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/imageF"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
```

Code from DialogFragment:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, container, false);
        View iv = v.findViewById(R.id.imageF);
        ((ImageView) iv).setImageResource(imgId);
        return v;
    }
```

But every time I get this:

[image: dialog doesn't fit to image]

Dialog doesn't fit to image. I get the same behavior using `AlertDialog` (also same SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303248/android-alert-dialog-does-not-fit-to-image)).

When trying to set image to background (`setBackgroundResource`) the image fits to dialog (image fills the unused space which is shown on the screenshot).

How to avoid this and fit dialog to image? Is there any workaround?

Help, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search and many unsuccessful attempts to solve this problem, I found a solution.

I needed to set `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`.